# Ignore failure codes from WebRequest?

Tags: c#, .net, webrequest

I'm calling an XML webservice URL from C# using standard WebRequest code:

```
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(MethodCall);
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream);
        string xml = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
```

The service in question returns XML; in case of errors you often still get XML returned with detailed error information, *however* it also returns an HTTP error code 400.
Running the query through Chrome I can see the XML and the error code in the dev-tools but my C# code throws a .Net `WebException` in the `GetResponse()` call so I never see the detailed error information.

Is there a way I can tell .Net not to throw exception but still to report the error code, so I can inspect the returned XML?

Answer (score 3):

Change `WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();` to

```
WebResponse response;
try
{
    response = request.GetResponse();
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
  response = (ex.Response as WebResponse);
  if (response == null)
      throw;
}
```

This should work.